# Sticky navbar ios issue

Tags: javascript, ios, css, navbar, sticky

I've been having several headaches for a while by trying to fix this issue, but unfortunately it seems I'm doing something wrong. I know there are several questions about this on the web and also here on StackOverflow, but by following the tips I just can't fix it. As you can see on the title, I'm facing with the very famous bug of iOS browsers (both Safari and Chrome). Infact, I dinamically detect the scroll with JS and add a class that makes the element fixed, but it doesn't work properly, as the position: fixed; become effective only at the end of the scroll.
This is my code:

CSS

```
.sticky{
    z-index: 99;
    position: static;
}
.sticky-enabled{
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
   -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
}
```

JS (angularJS)

```
angular.element(document).on("scroll", function(){
   if(angular.element(this).scrollTop() > 50){
      angular.element($scope.element).addClass("sticky-enabled");
   }else{
      angular.element($scope.element).removeClass("sticky-enabled");
   }
});
```

Thank you in advance and sorry for asking this again, but I just can't fix it!

Comment: Do you have a live url so i can look at this on my iPhone?

Comment: @NathanielFlick yes, you should be able to see the issue at [link](https://snapgle.com/photos)!